# General string quoting for TCL

Tags: tcl, quoting

I'm writing a utility (which happens to be in python) which is generating output in the form of a TCL script. Given some arbitrary string variable (not unicode) in the python, I want to produce a TCL line like

```
set s something
```

... which will set TCL variable '`s`' to that exact string, regardless of what strange characters are in it. Without getting too weird, I don't want to make the output messier than needed. I believe a decent approach is

1. if the string is not empty and contains only alphanumerics, and some characters like `.-_` (but definitely not `$"{}\`) then it can be used as-is;
2. if it contains only printable characters  and no double-quotes or curly braces (and does not end in backslash ) then simply put `{}` around it;
3. otherwise, put `""` around it after using `\` escapes for `"` `{` `}` `\` `$` `[` `]`  , and `\nnn` escapes for non-printing characters.

Question: is that the full set of characters which need escaping inside double quotes? I can't find this in the docs. And did I miss something (I almost missed that strings for (2) can't end in \ for instance).

I know there are many other strings which can be quoted by  `{}`, but it seems difficult to identify them easily. Also, it looks like non-printing characters (in particular, newline) are OK with (2) if you don't mind them being literally present in the TCL output.

Comment: What do you mean by \nnn for for non-printing characters?

Comment: @GaryWilloughby backslash followed by three octal digits is an escape which can be used for non-printing characters. I am aware that there are escapes for unicode; unicode is beyond the scope of my question but it's good to see that some answers are covering it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You really only need 2 rules,

- Escape curly braces
- Wrap the output in curly braces

You don't need to worry about newlines, non printable characters etc. They are valid in a literal string, and TCL has excellent Unicode support.

```
set s { 
this is
a 
long 
string. I have $10 [10,000 cents] only curly braces \{ need \} to be escaped.
\t is not  a real tab, but '    ' is. "quoting somthing" :
{matchin` curly braces are okay, list = string in tcl}
}
```

**Edit**
In light of your comment, you can do the following:

- escape `[]` `{}` and `$`
- wrap the whole output in `set s [subst { $output } ]`

The beauty of Tcl is it a has a very simple grammar. There are no other characters besides the 3 above needed to be escaped.

**Edit 2** One last try.

If you pass `subst` some options, you will only need to escape `\` and `{}`

`set s [subst -nocommands -novariables { $output } ]`

You would need to come up with a regex to convert non printable characters to their escaped codes however.

Good luck!

Comment: But I find this: escaping the curlies prevents them from being considered when finding the matching end-curly, but the backslashes are not removed (as they are for double-quotes) I.e. the result will still have the backslashes I added to the original curlies.

Comment: OK... I hadn't thought of using a TCL command to finish the job. But it looks like I then also need to escape backslash in addition to [] {} $ - so it's almost the same as the double-quote case (but not needing to escape ".) Escaping non-printable chars is something I would want to do even if not necessary.

Comment: Escaping curly braces doesn't seem to work because it just results in `\}` in the actual string.

Comment: Also "The beauty of Tcl is it a has a very simple grammar" seems to conflict with your three attempts to get this right!

Comment: For future googler's I recommend skipping past attempt 0 and 1 and go directly to the last try.

Answer (score 7):

Tcl has very few metacharacters once you're inside a double-quoted string, and all of them can be quoted by putting a backslash in front of them. The characters you must quote are `\` itself, `$` and `[`, but it's considered good practice to also quote `]`, `{` and `}` so that the script itself is embeddable. (Tcl's own `list` command does this, except that it doesn't actually wrap the double quotes so it also handles backslashes and it will also try to use other techniques on “nice” strings. There's an algorithm for doing this, but I advise not bothering with that much complexity in your code; simple universal rules are much better for correct coding.)

The second step is to get the data into Tcl. If you are generating a file, your best option is to write it as UTF-8 and use the `-encoding` option to tclsh/wish or to the `source` command to explicitly state what the encoding is. (If you're inside the same process, write UTF-8 data into a string and evaluate that. Job Done.) That option (introduced in Tcl 8.5) is specifically for dealing with this sort of problem:

```
source -encoding "utf-8" theScriptYouWrote.tcl
```

If that's not possible, you're going to have to fall back to adding additional quoting. The best thing is to then assume you've only got ASCII support available (a good lowest common denominator) and quote everything else *as a separate step to the quoting described in the first paragraph*. To quote, convert every Unicode character from U+00080 up to an escape sequence of the form `\uXXXX` where XXXX are exactly four hex digits<sup>[1]</sup> and the other two are literal characters. Don't use the `\xXX` form, as that has some “surprising” misfeatures (alas).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> There's an open bug in Tcl about handling characters outside the Basic Multilingual Pane, *part* of which is that the `\u` form isn't able to cope. Fortunately, non-BMP characters are still reasonably rare in practice.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell you must:

1. Enclose your string in double quotes `""`
2. Backslash-escape the following characters: `[`, `$`, `"` and `\`.

The other answers are wrong in various ways:

- You *do* need to escape `"`.
- You *do not* need to escape `]`, `{`, or `}` in double-quoted strings.
- You cannot use `{this style of string}` because there's no way to put unbalanced curly brackets in it. `{ \} }` does not work because it keeps the backslash in the string.

The spec is very unclear about this, and even wrong in some places (e.g. it says `\n` will be replaced with a newline in `{curley bracket strings}` but that doesn't actually happen. So I figured this out mostly from experimentation on repl.it.

Answer (score 2):

To do it right you should also specify the encoding your python string is in, typically sys.getdefaultencoding(). Otherwise you might garble encodings when translating it to Tcl.

If you have binary data in your string and want Tcl binary strings as a result this will always work:

```
data = "".join("\\u00%02x" % ord(c) for c in mystring)
tcltxt = "set x %s" % data
```

Will look like a hex dump though, but well, it is a hex dump...

If you use any special encoding like UTF-8 you can enhance that a bit by using encoding convertfrom/convertto and the appropriate Python idiom.

```
data = "".join("\\u00%02x" % ord(c) for c in myutf8string)
tcltext = "set x [encoding convertfrom utf-8 %s]" % data
```

You can of course refine this a bit, avoiding the \u encoding of all the non special chars, but the above is safe in any case.